# aspectj error while compiling with Maven

Tags: maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I just checked out a project from SVN, built with maven and aspectj.

When I try to compile with Maven (tried with original version 3.2.5 and with the latest 3.3.3), I get the following error (just an excerpt of the long log I get with the -X option):

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (default-aj-generate-sources) @ jcz-persistence-jpa ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[ERROR] The type org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    [path to class].java:0
(no source information available)
```

I've been looking unsuccessfully into it for the last hours: does anyone know what is the cause of that?

Comment: The error means that a class cannot be found, likely because you're missing [this dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans).

Comment: @Kenney nope, dependency is correctly added. Editing the question,adding this info.

Comment: Ok, probably a classloader issue in the plugin; try adding that dependency to the [plugin dependency section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag).